# How to pass type to getelementptr via LLVM C API?

Tags: llvm

I want to implement a function f whose only parameter is a pointer to a vector of 2 int and returns the second element of the vector. That is `f :: <2 * i32> * --> int`.

I think it should generate code like this: 

`getelementptr i32, <2 x i32>* %a, i32 1`

I am using LLVM C API, I fail to manage it to generate code like above. I find that `LLVMBuildGEP` is implemented as `wrap(unwrap(B)->CreateGEP(nullptr, unwrap(Pointer), IdxList, Name));`. Does it mean that we can only pass nullptr to `CreateGEP` if we are using LLVM C API?

How can I generate the code like above using LLVM C API?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

from 
http://llvm.org/doxygen/IR_2Core_8cpp_source.html
core.cpp:2897

```
 LLVMValueRef LLVMBuildGEP(LLVMBuilderRef B, LLVMValueRef Pointer,
                           LLVMValueRef *Indices, unsigned NumIndices,
                           const char *Name) {
   ArrayRef<Value *> IdxList(unwrap(Indices), NumIndices);
   return wrap(unwrap(B)->CreateGEP(nullptr, unwrap(Pointer), IdxList, Name));
 }
```

if you are using LLVMBuildGEP(C-API) you need to pass BuilderRef, Pointer(pointer to your vector), Indices(in your case it is i32 1), Numindices(also one) and name.
The code in core.cpp is a wrapper which unwraps the C-API call and calls c++ one.

Now that being said.
I strongly advised against using the GEP for vector element extraction. it causes some problems with optimizations for some combinations(personal experience).
You can use extractelement(LLVMBuildExtractElement C-interface) to extract vector element.

if you are interested you can read more about GEP here.https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#extractelement-instruction
and complete C-interface list here http://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMCCoreInstructionBuilder.html#gaf392c575dd594d83894d3e71a520ffa4
P.S.:not sure if above links are updated ones or not.